# How to find the string in the list of .gz files?

Tags: linux, files, gzip

I have a list of folders in each folder I have around 600 .gz files which are automatically generated by the system every 15 min. I need to display the particular string which is repeated in that .gz files. And find the .gz file which the string is located?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"the particular string which is repeated"*? In general, you can use `zgrep` to search within GZIPed data. Can you give a more complete description of what you are trying to do?

Comment: a compressed string of bytes, or a string of bytes that has now been compressed to something else? Also, what does "repeated" mean? is 2 instances sufficient, or what is?

Answer (score 2):

Given some top-level directory, `topdir`, under which all your compressed files are located, and assuming that you are using a GNU implementation of `zgrep`:

```
zgrep -R -l -F --include='*.gz' -e 'string' topdir
```

This would search for `string` as a substring in any of the `gzip`-compressed files under `topdir` and would return the pathnames of all matching files.

Using `zgrep` on a system without GNU `zgrep`, you likely can't use `--include`.  This may not be an issue if your `topdir` only contains compressed files, but if you want to only search the file with `.gz` filename suffix, you may do

```
find topdir -type f -name '*.gz' -exec zgrep -l -F -e 'string' {} +
```

This would find all regular files with names ending in `.gz` under `topdir` and will run the given `zgrep` command on as large batches of these as possible.

If you don't even have `zgrep`, you could do

```
find topdir -type f -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if gzip -dc "$pathname" | grep -q -F -e 'string'; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This extracts each file and passes it through ordinary `grep`.  If a line is found that contains the given string, the pathname of the file is printed.

Notice how the "internal" shell script is a loop that could easily be modified to work on all `*.gz`-files in a single directory:

```
for pathname in ./*.gz; do
    if gzip -dc "$pathname" | grep -q -F -e 'string'; then
        printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

If you want to match `string` as a complete word and not as a substring, then add `-w` to the invocations of `grep` above.  If `string` is something that you'd like to be interpreted as a regular expression, remove `-F`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to find whether the string appears in some .gz files under one folder:

```
zgrep the_string  *.gz -l
```

To do this for a list of folders that are all in one folder:

```
find . -name "*.gz" | xargs zgrep the_string -l
```

For example, the output is like this:

```
./tmp/2/F.tar.gz
./tmp/2/F1.tar.gz
./tmp/1/F.tar.gz
./tmp/1/F1.tar.gz
```

Now you get the list of files that contain the string.

Comment: `zgrep` likely has a `-R` option to do recursive grepping across a directory hierarchy, and also a `-l` option to return only the pathnames of the matching files. Most of yeur pipeline is not needed.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. Yes, `-l` option is good. I have updated my answer. However, the `-R` option is not supported with `zgrep`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for duplicate strings that are not known beforehand, here's a script that will look for duplicate words in a set of files (a word here means anything the has spaces around it):

```
#!/bin/bash

dup_words() {
    zcat $1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sed '/^$/d' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{if ($1 > 1) m=1; } END { exit(!m) } '
}

for i in *.gz
do
    dup_words $i && echo $i
done
```

It will split lines at every occurance of a space, then remove empty lines, find and count occurrences, and finally check for more than 1 occurrence.

The loop just outputs the filename, and you can adjust the action after `&&` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command -

```
zgrep "foo" $(find . -name "*.gz")
```